# Podio: AttributeError: module 'pypodio2' has no attribute 'OAuthAppClient'

Tags: python, podio

```
import pypodio2 as pod

MY_CLIENT_ID = 'myclientid'
MY_CLIENT_SECRET = 'myclientsecret'

pod.OAuthAppClient(MY_CLIENT_ID, MY_CLIENT_SECRET)
try:
    authenticate_with_password(myemail,mypassword)

    print('success!!!!')
except:
    print('something went wrong, sorry')
```

Trying to run the above code in Python 3, I get the error that

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\justatry.py", line 6, in 
>       pod.OAuthAppClient(MY_CLIENT_ID, MY_CLIENT_SECRET)
>   AttributeError: module 'pypodio2' has no attribute 'OAuthAppClient'

What is wrong? When I look in the api.py in the pypodio2-library, I can see that there is such a function. Why can't I access it?

Edit: Doing this in the shell (which gives me all the classes, functions, methods etc when I try e.g. tkinter):

```
import pypodio2
dir(pypodio2)
```

Only gives me:

> ['_ _builtins__', '_ _cached__', '_ _doc__', '_ _file__', '_ _loader__', '_ _name__', '_ _package__', '_ _path__', '_ _spec__']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your import

```
from pypodio2.api import OAuthAppClient
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do that, I did that in the shell and it gave me this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'urlencode'

Comment: It seems that 'api' imports 'transport' which imports 'urlencode' from 'urllib', and that seems to give me the error

Comment: Yes you can do that. pypodio2 is a package containing modules (api, ....), so to import/access a function on a module, you need to import in the above fashion. from package.module import function.

Comment: having said that, most developers will import the functions in package __init__.py file, so imports look much cleaner/efficient. Check http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, that blog post definitely cleared up some confusion.